# ros electric navigation

Tags: navigation, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is ros-electric-navigation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12533/ros-electric-navigation/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-01-05**:
Yeah, I need help installing the navigation stack. Unless I am suppose to create the package myself based on the following:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Creating_a_Package

I assumed that it was simply a download like other packages.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2012-01-05**:
Can you be more specific as to what you mean here? Are you looking for documentation? Help on installing the navigation stack? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu, you should be able to install the navigation stack as follows:

`sudo apt-get install ros-electric-navigation`

For details on installing ROS in general, please have a look at: http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-01-05**:
Hey Eitan.  Thanks for the help.  The problem was definitely that my repository for synaptic wasn't updating properly.

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-01-05**:
That's what I thought, but I get this message when trying to run that command: E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-navigation.  I just noticed that my other computer it shows up, which tells me that I my synaptic manager isn't setup properly.